# Code seems correct but the program hangs after printing the first row of the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to implement matrix using pointer. The code seems correct but the program hangs after printing the first row of the array.

```
int main ()
    {
        int **a;
        int i,j;
        int count = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                *(*(a + i) + j) = count;
                count += 1;
                printf("%d\t", *(*(a + i) + j));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course the supplied code doesn't work. Add some example data so that we don't get to dereference `NULL` at once.

Comment: So after all, is it really the **compiler** that hangs, and not your program?

Comment: The compiler doesn't print rows of the array, but the program attempts to do so.  I've fixed the question accordingly.

Comment: You have not initialized `a` or given it any space to point to.  Using it leads to inherently undefined behaviour; it is amazing it didn't crash _before_ printing the first row of the array.

Comment: I suggest that you remove the "code seems correct" assertion in this question.  Quite evidently it is not correct (as it does not work), so  you may avoid unnecessary ridicule by being a little less confident in your broken code.

Comment: @D-side : There is no guarantee (in fact it is unlikely) that `a` will be null - so it is worse than that; at least the runtime is likely to recognise and trap a null dereference, while dereferencing a merely uninitialized pointer is non-deterministic.

Comment: @Clifford yes, you are correct. I wanted to point out that this code clearly shouldn't work and it doesn't reproduce the problem because there is no matrix defined.

Comment: Once you've fixed the lack of memory allocation, you can also replace `*(*(a + i) + j)` with `a[i][j]`.

Answer (score 2):

This will work!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int **a;
    int i,j;
    int count = 1;
    // Allocate memory and populate 
    a = malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        a[i] = malloc(4*sizeof(int));
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        { 
            *(*(a + i) + j) = count;
            count += 1;
            printf("%d\t", *(*(a + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //Now free the allocated memory
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

`**a` is just a pointer to pointer, however in your code you have not specified where this pointer should point to.

First you need to allocate memory before using it and then perform the desired operation (populate, read, write etc) and once you no longer require it, free the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

For the code to stand a chance of working, you must allocate space for the array, and space for the pointers.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int   m[4][4];
    int  *p[4] = { m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3] };
    int **a = p;
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            *(*(a + i) + j) = count++;
            printf("%d\t", *(*(a + i) + j));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways of specifying `m` and `p`.  For example:

```
int m[16];
int *p[4] = { &m[0], &m[4], &m[8], &m[12] };
```

Answer (score 0):

What is missing from your code is the allocation of memory. When you say `int** a;` you only get the double pointer variable, no space for the pointer that it should point to, and no space for the integer that the intermediate pointer should point to. Dereferencing such an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.

Now, the easiest way to allocate a matrix in C, is to allocate an array of arrays like this:

```
int main() {
    int n = 4, count = 1;
    int (*matrix)[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(*matrix));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = count++;
        }
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

`malloc()` allocates the memory, `free()` gives it back so that it can be reused. `matrix` is a pointer to a line array of the matrix, and the `malloc()` call allocates enough memory for `n` elements of whatever `matrix` points to (that is `n` line arrays of `n` elements in this case). You can't do the allocation more concise.